# My media query doesn’t work in CSS, it doesn’t seem recognized

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the @media working on my CSS but it doesn’t seem to work.

In the <head> of my HTML code, I have :

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In my style.css :

```css
.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background: #2e2c2c;
}
```

(I precise that my .sidebar is display: block by default)
And then :

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
  }
```

I expect my .sidebar to be display: none like I wrote, but it still display: block and in the inspector, I didn’t see any traces of media query.
I tried with a window smaller than 1366px large on my browser and by emulating the phone screen, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a special character in your code causing issues, here is the same code from your example with the hidden special character in the media query removed. The special character is in the space between `max-width:` and `1366px`.

```css
.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background: #2e2c2c;
    color: white;
}
main {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
  .sidebar {
      display: none;
  }
  main {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<main>Main</main>
```